# Manage User Records in ADB2C

Tags: c#, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I’ve integrated B2C with a web app to handle a user management and authentication process. And we have migrated on-prem users to B2C identity store via C# console app. Here is a scenario, where we have to identify the users that are not logged in / inactive for more than 120 days, then we have to disable or delete those user accounts from B2C AD. Need some help to handle this process and in a automate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days) as a guide.

Every time the user logs in, update the extension attribute.

You will have to write a batch Graph API process to go through B2C and find all inactive accounts and then set:

```
 "accountEnabled": false
```